# would it be possible to reference the Navigation properties as FK in a many to many relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

assume there are two entities

```cs
    public class Order
        {
            public int OrderId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
            public Customer Customer { get; set; }
            public int PaymentType { get; set; }
            public int ItemCount { get; set; }
            public List<OrderProducts> OrdenesProductos { get; set; }
            public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
            public int  PaymentId { get; set; }
            public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        }
```

```cs
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; } 
        public double Price { get; set; }        
    }
```

and I would like to add  table toat adds the many to many entries for each Order placed

```cs
    public class OrderProducts
        {
            [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
            public Order Order { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            [Key]
            public int OrderProductId { get; set; }
        }
```

in appdbcontext i would set the foreign keys

```cs
  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>().HasKey(k => new {k.Product.ProductId, k.Order.OrderId });
            }
```

but would it be possible to do this in an anonymous object, could it be possible with a different call to this table to have 2 foreign keys from orders and  products by referencing the OrderProducts's navigation object's PK?

Comment: The PK and FK can be shadow properties. Which should be auto-defined based on your `[ForeignKey("...")]` attributes. But I don't think you can (or should) define the key in terms of the navigation property. Instead use the `.HasKey(String[])` method.

Comment: Many-to-many relationships require a collection navigation property on both sides. They will be discovered by convention like other types of relationships

Comment: @JeremyLakeman so how could i be able to reference the property name as a string? Namespace.OrderProducts.Order.OrderId  Namespace.OrderProducts.Product.ProductId or how?

Comment: `[ForeignKey(nameof(Order.OrderId))]` .... `.HasKey(new string[]{ nameof(Order.OrderId), ... })` ?

Comment: @Jazb you say I am msising a List<Order> in the Product table. i get it, but what I really want is to split the Order's items in a sepated table but can I use the navigation property's  as FK and PK? instead adding a 2 int fields?

Comment: @Jazb While a `.HasMany().WithMany()` join would require navigations, the question is an example of an "indirect many-to-many" join.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes you are right you can call the property name ´s PK and it will make it a FK in the many to many relationship thanks